# SQL custom sort

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named Tasks as shown below. Fields in the table are employees, tasks, and date.

Input table :

```
Date:       employees   Task
2016-12-03  John    Paint the walls pink
2016-12-03  Sam     Play hockey on linoleum
2016-12-03  John    the golden fish in a bucket
2016-12-03  Sam     Create a rink on the porch
2016-12-03  Nathan  Glue the front door
2016-12-03  Nathan  Paint the walls pink
2016-12-08  Sam     Melt the doorknob
2016-12-08  Dewey   Wrap the cat in toilet paper
2016-12-08  John    Give bubble gum to the dog
2016-12-08  Dewey   Order 20 pizzas
2016-12-09  John    Create a rink on the porch
2016-12-09  Nathan  Eat all the candies
.......
...... so on
```

For Output, I want to select a list which would be sorted according to date first and then according to specific Order of employee (John come first, Nathan second, sam Third, Dewey fourth).

```
Output:
    Date:       employees   Task
    2016-12-03  John    Paint the walls pink
    2016-12-03  John    the golden fish in a bucket
    2016-12-03  sam     Play hockey on linoleum
    2016-12-03  Sam     Create a rink on the porch
    2016-12-03  Nathan  Glue the front door

..
..
.... so on.
```

I tried using ORDER BY.
How can I get the Sorting done in the specific sequence as mentioned above?
Or do I need to know some other concept? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look at `ORDER BY FIELD`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`FIELD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function. Details of the function are:

```
FIELD(str,str1,str2,str3,...)
```

> Returns the index (position) of str in the str1, str2, str3, ... list.
>   Returns 0 if str is not found.

Now, the `FIELD(employees, 'John', 'Nathan', 'Sam', 'Dewey')` function will return **0** if the `employees` is not in `('John', 'Nathan', 'Sam', 'Dewey')`.

So, if we use `ORDER BY FIELD(employees, 'John', 'Nathan', 'Sam', 'Dewey')` only, other **non-matching** rows will appear at the top. So, we can use [`If()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function to return **1** for the other **non-matching** rows, and **0** for the matched rows.

Now, we can utilize one more level of ordering by `FIELD(employees, 'John', 'Nathan', 'Sam', 'Dewey')`. This will ensure that the matched id(s) appear first in the order as specified in the `Field()` function.

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
ORDER BY `date` ASC, 
          IF(FIELD(employees, 'John', 'Nathan', 'Sam', 'Dewey') = 0, 1, 0) ASC, 
          FIELD(employees, 'John', 'Nathan', 'Sam', 'Dewey') ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FIELD()` function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
ORDER BY `date` ASC, FIELD(employees, 'John', 'Nathan', 'Sam', 'Dewey')
```

The only caveat is if you have *other* employees.  The above logic will put them first.

So, you might want something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
ORDER BY `date` ASC,
          COALESCE(NULLIF(FIELD(employees, 'John', 'Nathan', 'Sam', 'Dewey'), 0), 999999)
```

I'm using the `COALESCE(NULLIF())` combination to avoid repeating the list of employees.  Another alternative is the reverse list:

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
ORDER BY `date` ASC,
          FIELD(employees, 'Dewey', 'Sam', 'Nathan', 'John') DESC
```